# PHP date conversion from Facebook API

Tags: php, datetime

I have a problem by converting a date in proper format.
I get the time the from Facebook API in this format: `2013-08-23T09:00:00`
I then `$fbdate = date('2013-08-23T09:00:00');`

When I `echo $fbdate`, it retuns `2013-08-25UTC05:00:00`.

Then I tried:

```
$datum = date("d.m.Y",$fbdate);
$uhrzeit = date("H:i",$fbdate);
```

To extract the date and the time but it always returns: 
`01.01.1970` for `$datum` and `00:33` for `$uhrzeit`.

Comment: What do you expect? From what I read in the manuals, the behaviour that you describe is prefectly correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `strtotime()` to parse a date string into a UNIX timestamp:

```
$fbdate = strtotime('2013-08-23T09:00:00');

$datum = date('d.m.Y', $fbdate);
$uhrzeit = date('H:i', $fbdate);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [DateTime](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$fbdate = '2013-08-23T09:00:00';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $fbdate);

$datum = $date->format('d.m.Y');
$uhrzeit = $date->format('H:i');

echo $datum;
echo $uhrzeit;
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using the DateTime-class while the date-function is capable of doing what you want, when you want it to be done? (Curiosity question...)

Comment: I find it a lot easier to work with for formatting if you need the date in different formats (internationalization, for instance). But I think the biggest benefit is using it in conjunction with `DateInterval` when calling `diff` for calculating differences. Then again, maybe that's just me.

Comment: Ok, clear. Just saw the diff-function and seems handy. I'm just used to calculate with timestamps but this is nice too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$datum = date("d.m.Y",strtotime($fbdate));
$uhrzeit = date("H:i",strtotime($fbdate));
```

The `date` function in PHP is meant to convert a `microtime` into a date, so you need to convert your string dates to `microtime`s first.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? You should use `strtotime()` when using the `date` function.

```
$datum = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($fbdate));
$uhrzeit = date("H:i", strtotime($fbdate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **strtotime()**

```
$a = date("Y-M-d", strtotime($datum)); 
echo $a.$uhrzeit;
```

More info http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a huge fan of using timestamp.

What I did to solve this issue was:

```
$updatedDate = new DateTime(
   preg_replace('/^(.*)\+0000$/', '$1', $fbUser->getProperty("updated_time")),
   new DateTimeZone("UTC")
);
```

It chops the +0000 part and creates the DateTime object with an explicit UTC timezone.